# Deployed release mode apk first install - RealmMigration must be provided

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, realm

I get the exception "RealmMigration must be provided" on first run of a deployed app on an android phone (placed on the device via "adb install app-release.apk"

The code it's going through from within onCreate of main activity are the following 2 lines:

```
Realm.init(context);
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

The exception occurs on the call to getDefaultInstance(). This occurs only within a signed release apk.
If I clear all storage data and uninstall the app, then redeploy, it will always happen.

Once I clear the storage data but do not uninstall, it stops happening.

If I clear all storage data and uninstall and then debug the app through android studio, it does not happen.

What could cause this?

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: Do you have `assetFile()` specified in the configuration?

Comment: I don't have assetFile specified.  Is that required?  It's not mentioned in the first immediate documentation of Realm.  I noticed that the problem goes away if I deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().  Obviously that's not a solution once the app is being sold, but I think this shows that when uninstalling a release app, the data file of realm must be somewhere else - because that doesn't get deleted.  Any idea on that part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the culprit.  Go in the phone's "Settings | General | Backup & reset | Automatic restore".  That was on.  So "When reinstalling an app, restore backed up settings and data".  The old version of the database would be revived just before my app would start again!  HOLY COW ANNOYING!  :)

Thank you very very much for your assistance- much appreciated, but this was the real issue here!  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

It happens because you don't setup default schema configuration in your *application* `onCreate()` method. You can create schema using [schema builder](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#the-default-realmconfiguration):

```
// The Realm file will be located in Context.getFilesDir() with name "default.realm"
Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

But take a note, this way is used only if your objects model is not changes. You have two variant of running your application with "unstable" objects model:

#### For development:

You can build realm shema without migration at development stage using `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` method:

```
Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

In this case database will be automaticly dropped and recreated if objects model have any changes.

#### For production

You need to write migration scripts, if your want to keep data. In this case you need to build database schema with *schema version* and manually manage this version like in example below:

```
Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
    .schemaVersion(2) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
    .migration(new MyMigration()) // Migration to run instead of throwing an exception
    .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

Read more about migration rules at this [documentation chapter](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations) and in [sample application](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/migrationExample)

Comment: I suspected that as well.  However, I had tried the following with no luck:         `RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
                .Builder()
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config); Followed by realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()`.  Didn't work until I added deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded.

Comment: Hi again Sergey. I saw that the init happens in the application class. I was doing it in each activity. That's at least one thing I was doing wrong. I'll try that change tomorrow evening and come back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... I thought it was fixed, but it's still asking me for migration.  I did the init just once in a new Application object.  But each activity that calls Realm.getDefaultInstance always asks for migration - even after uninstalling the app.  I'm a bit stuck...

Comment: Is it wrong to have multiple objects that get a handle on realm with Realm.getDefaultInstance()?  I suspect this could be my problem.

Comment: And then again, the fact that this only happens in release mode, not in debug mode....  I don't get it.

Comment: Perhaps it's normal?  On my own device, the app has been installed.  I get the migration errors.  If I do not uninstall and just delete the app's data, the errors go away.

Comment: @MikeGagnon. I think, you have a trouble with migrations errors because of once you created database with version signature like for *production mode*. I have changed my answer for clarify this

Comment: Thank you Sergey for your continued input.  I understand what you are saying, except I am not making any changes to my models at this point.  After uninstalling an app completely, there is no data.  Running the app again should not cause "RealmMigration must be provided" to occur, immediately after the uninstall.  Does this make sense to you?  How could that happen?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134441/discussion-between-sergey-and-mike-gagnon).

Comment: Hi Sergey, all I had to do was disable the backup and restore feature on android. It is solved. Sorry I missed your chat request but I think you didn't realize I was saying it's fixed now by disabling that option while reinstalling the app. I'd be happy to explain in more detail if you need...

Comment: Yes, not obvious, but my old different database was being restored as I was reinstalling the app with the new version because of the backup and restore feature on android.

Comment: Really have a look at the setting, it's worth it - "Go in the phone's "Settings | General | Backup & reset | Automatic restore"